# jQuery mobile: problem with submitting forms due to page transitions

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm a bit confused with something i am trying to do in jquery mobile.  I have about 5 pages total in my site and every page has the same webform on it. I've written a script that processes the form using jquery ajax. All of that works on the index.html.

I have a page2 div in my index.html that serves as a second page of my website, however the form doesnt appear to work.

I also have a page3.html page. When i go to this page, it has the same form that i had from my homepage, but it doesn't take any of jquery js, like I am hiding p.error lines using jquery, it works fine on the homepage, but doesn't trigger at all on the internal page.

Is there a way to fix this? What is the general recommendation in jquery mobile when it comes to have the same exact form across the entire website? Right now, i can only get the webform to work on my homepage.

Here is some code from the site, first the js.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.error').hide();

     $(function() {
     $(".button").click(function() {
     ... form validations go here ...
     ... using $.ajax({ type: "post", data: datastring }) ...
```

I just put an excerpt of the js code.  It might be that the document.read function only loads on the homepage and then all interior pages are losing that script.  So, pages that are not the index.htl, should i trigger my form script differently?

I wrap each page in a div like this:

```
<div id="container" data-role="page">... my page content code here ...</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page">... my page content code here ...</div>
```

Each page has the same form in it, but when i go to page2, the form validates but it also conflicts with the other form so i cant submit it because it will always see the form fields as blank.

Each page contains links to other pages. When i click to go to a page that is not index or page2, nothing works on the form (my p.error statements are visible, click the submit button sends me to a 405 error page). When I submit the form from the homepage everything works exactly as expected. If i don't choose something from the drop down, it shows my p.error phrases. if i leave my email address field blank, it will show the p.error phrase to show the error message.

I am pretty sure the issue is how jquery mobile hijacks the scripts and loads things into the DOM and i had read that i can only load javascript once on the homepage. is that true?

The end result  i am looking for is a way to have a fully functioning form with form validation on every page of the site whether it is a stacked data-role page or an external data-role page and i want to keep all of the animated transitions.

Comment: I think we will need some source code to debug this. What jQuery selectors are you using?

Comment: each page and form should have a unique id that jQM can access

Comment: Yes, i just double checked that. On my external page, i didnt have a unique id, but now i do. Making the ID unique didn't seem to change anything.  If this helps when i go to http://mydomain.com/mobile/index.html everything works.  When i go to http://mydomain.com/mobile/otherpage.html, everything works. Where things fall apart is when things are loaded into the DOM via jqmobile and the hash tag, like http://mydomain.com/mobile/index.html#otherpage.html - on this page, the javascript script that i have on the homepage that processes the form doesnt seem to run because I can see p.error msgs.

Comment: The error msgs are visible so it looks like that script doesn't get loaded. Is there a way that i can call the script after jqmobile loads?  I saw some things in the documentation that makes me think that i can do this, but the documentation was not very clear how the syntax might look.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the flaws of jQuery Mobile, I've learned something while looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from scratch.
Turns out form submission is Ajaxified by default, [RTFM here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html).
And [this is how](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) you handle it in jQuery.

From this, I've created 2 pages and submit button only submits the form it resides in, which is what you need!

Page1:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {    
            $("form").submit(function () { // important: form selector, not ID
                if (!confirm("Index submit?"))
                    return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="form1" method="post" action="index.html">
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
            <a href="otherpage.html">Other Page</a>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Page 2:

```
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () { // important: form selector, not ID
                if (!confirm("Other page submit?"))
                    return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Other Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content"> 
        <form id="form2" method="post" action="otherpage.html">  
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
            <a href="index.html">Home Page</a> 
        </form>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Try this, replacing my `!confirm("Other page submit?")` with yours if `!IsFromValid()` and it should be good to go!
If it works, you owe me a pint, mate =)

Comment: awesome mate, yes, I will try that out today. I believe that that solution will work because that will submit the form that is focus when i click the submit button. Before i was triggering the submit based on the class of the submit button. I'll let you know and if it works, i'll be sure to hook you up. thanks for the help.

Comment: yep, jquery mobile does in fact process forms via ajax automatically, but i've turned off this feature and wrote my own script so I have form validation running. We will see if my form validation continues to get in the way of submitting the forms.  Hopefully by selecting the form attribute instead of the class of the button, i should be ok because its only going to submit one of the forms and not all of them.

Comment: sadly, it still conflicts with the form validation. Each form is exactly the same, exccept i've assigned unique form id="form1", form id="form2" etc to each form. All of the actual form fields are the same so the form is in memory at the moment for each page that gets loaded. i'd like to unload it and reload it.

Comment: I suppose, i could write the entire in javascript and load it from .js file and then when the page moves unload it and reload it?

Comment: ok, i broke my pages apart and tried your code in a more simplistic page.  I could get it to work, but ultimately what I found was this article: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-form-validation.html and i'm using the jquery validation plugin to validate the form and it seems to work as long as i don't go from index to page2 and then back to index via a link, using the jqm back button doesn't confuse it and i'm able to submit both forms independently.  I will test it further tomorrow AM, but i think i might have a solution now. shew!

Comment: i reckon there should be a way to get it working **with** the jQuery Mobile navigation in place. Can't you pass appropriate formId to your Validation function?

Comment: Your answer above was really close and helped me get to the point where i am now.  I switched a little bit though. I'm using jquery validation plugin from bassistence.de.  Great plugin. And as you suggested I'm putting my JS right after the data-role="page" so its within the page.  But an additional step I needed to do was I neeed to make the formID of each form unique and also all IDs on elememts of the form. so firstname had ID of firstname1 on homepage and firstname2 on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm with you now. Basically, what I've managed to replicate is a simple jQuery call that works on initial `index.html` page load, stops working when you navigate away and come back to this page, the url becoming something like `index.html#index.html`.

This is caused by jQuery mobile AJAXified page transitions, which has a few limitations mentioned [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/docs-transitions.html#/test/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html) (under "Known limitations"), one of which being:

> Any unique assets referenced by pages
>   in a jQuery Mobile-driven site should
>   be **placed inside the "page" element**
>   (the element with a data-role
>   attribute of "page"). For example,
>   links to styles and **scripts** that are
>   specific to a particular page can be
>   referenced inside that div.

So, basically, what it is saying is you need to move your JavaScript inside the `<div data-role="page"></div>`. This worked for me.

Comment: yep, i have that as my basic shell, but you will see, I elaborated on my question.  Try putting the same form on multiple pages and submiting that form. I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If there is a way to trigger some javascript on interior pages that are loaded via ajax then i think i can get this to work. is it possible?

Comment: can you try my solution, please?

Comment: interesting, I will try that out.

Comment: hmm, ok, so i moved the form validation script to a formval.js. I placed the script within the div for the page. I put the form on the homepage and one interior page. I made sure each form had its own unique ID.  But still when i press submit the form submits both forms (the one from the homepage and the one from page2 so i can't submit the script on the interior page. The issue might be the method i use to submit the form. I'm using $(".button").click() to submit the form. Both submit buttons have the class "button" on them.  Will a multi-select in the script work here?

Comment: you're right, it does! that's really poor :( so i guess you are going to have to use unique selectors for the click() event listener. E.g. using IDs you mentioned in your question, it'd be `$("#container .button").click()` and `$("#page2 .button").click()`

Comment: I ran into the problem before using jqtouch. I'm convinced it is definitely related to the way the "page" is loaded with ajax into the DOM.

Comment: well one other thing to possibly try...Is there a way to load scripts into view after the transition?  I wrapped my app into a phonegap app and i can see that here is the order how things are being processed. I added an alert to a script block with the "page2". starting from the home and click the page2 link, i see the alert, then the loading graphic, then the transition, then the new page and the script is not being loaded. So, i think all i need to do is trigger my scripts after the transition somehow. Do you know how i could do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. The click() events work for me using different button selectors as per my previous comment. I guess submitting should work as well.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand myself sometimes :) ... i was able to do this...$('#page2').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
 alert('this page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
 $('.ajaxtrigger').trigger('click');
}); /// and this script would trigger my alert after the transition

Comment: btw, sir, thanks very much for your assist on this, I've been having this same problem and havent ever figured out a solution to it yet.

Comment: sorry i went on a tangent there...question, if i decide to use multiselector, would i have to write multiple versions of the same script OR can i attach the multiselector to the one script, but its only triggered if button1 is click or button2 is click, but not both of them at the same time. does that make sense?

Comment: well you can't really click 2 buttons at exact same time :) so it'll only fire once even if you use multiseletor, like so: `$("#button1Id,#button2Id").click()`. Just make sure the common script is referenced inside the page container div on both pages.

Comment: i suppose what i meant was i want when i click .button1 to run the script for the form with ID of Form1 and when i click button2, i want it to run for the script with ID Form2 and so on...Right now when i click .button, it submits all of the forms.

Comment: including a small script that attaches the script to head tag is working well.  However, I'm still getting both forms being submitted, so now i just to figure out how to target the form properly so only one form gets submitted via one script for form validation and ajax submission since its the same form across the board on every page.

Comment: something like this, i get the alerts and i see the form is initiated because my p.error tags become hidden. $('#page2').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
 
 alert('this page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
 $('.ajaxtrigger').trigger('click');
 
 
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";

script.onload = function(){
 alert("here!");
};

script.src = "js/formVal.v1.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})

Comment: ok, so how about this, i cant seem to get the right combination of goodness down from my ideas above.  No matter what i do its still submitting both forms, which sucks because that means i can't really send the data because my form validation will choke somewhere.  So, my latest question: 1. is there a way to only enable the form that is being submitted and disbale all other forms?

Comment: OR is there a way to load and unload the form with each new "page"?  If i use $('#somediv').remove(); to remove the form, is there a way i can add it back?